# A Living Sound Effect Library

Tags: birds, sounds

I don't know if any of you have seen this but I just found it while looking up bird songs on youtube and I was pretty amazed..

[Bird Songs Video Link](http://youtu.be/VjE0Kdfos4Y)

Comment: +1 Wow... That guy from Police Academy has met his match. BTW, is that the narrator who narrated Blue Planet?

Comment: @Utopia Yeah he did but he did THE Blue Planet not the other by Ben Burtt and his brother was John Hammond in Jurassic Park lol.

Comment: Mindblowing...! 

Comment: @Stephen Wow I didn't know they were brothers! Hah! Are you serious? Learn something new every day..

Comment: Awesome.. I loved this series. One of my wishlist items to buy this year is Sir David Attenborough's The Life Collection Box Set... a box full of nature goodies. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: amazing!  But does it record 24 bit 192khz?

Comment: Average lifespan: Lyrebird 15, Harddrive 5. African grey parrots can live 50+ years but can you teach one the 6000 series?

Comment: Absolutely incredible!

Comment: That's Aussie ingenuity for you :) I suspect he records analogue

Comment: I'd like to have one in the studio :)

Comment: The bit with the chainsaws always catches me off guard! Amazing.

Comment: Hahaha awesome!! Thanks Big car chase scenes with RPGs and helicopters shooting 50 cal machine guns???? No problem. Ill just use my bird.

Comment: THAT is a sound designer!

Comment: Has anyone done research to see if they can have this bird learn more sounds? Maybe have it listen to Michael Jackson or to "The Bird is the Word"

Comment: trust David Attenborough to find that bird among all the species out there.

Comment: Someone should make an impulse response of it.

Comment: Saw one of these in real life at Healesville Sanctuary near Melbourne and it imitated the sounds of tourists saying "wow" and also taking photos. My wife told me about one lyre bird living near her house in Melbourne that would impersonate cop cars and an old steam train so well that people would go outside to look for the train.

Comment: What is actually asked here?

Comment: It's from before the merge with Stack Exchange. It is indeed  not a question, but it is very interesting, we shouldn't close this.